# Moveable EditText hiding issue when open keyboard in Android

Tags: android

According to my need i have implemented move-able EditText on over the screen but getting problem is that when EditText move to bottom and open keyboard, then EditText getting hide and does'nt show. how can i resolved this.
   editText.setOnTouchListener(ImageStickerActivity.this);

```
 float newDx;
float newDy;
int latAPerformedAction;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            newDy = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
            latAPerformedAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            isMoving = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float newY = event.getRawY() + newDy;

            if (newY <= 0 || newY >= screenHight - view.getHeight()) {
                latAPerformedAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;

                break;
            }
            isMoving = true;
            view.setY(newY);
            latAPerformedAction = MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (latAPerformedAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                isMoving = false;
            break;

        default:
            isMoving = false;
            return false;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: show your move-able edittext code

Comment: check my updated ques

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works with your custom EditText implementation, but you can try and set the following attribute in your AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> ... </activity>
```

If that doesn't work, you could alternatively add an event listener to see when the viewport changes. This is a common method to retrieve events when the keyboard gets shown or hidden. Then you move your EditText up or down as much pixels as the viewport changes. This way, the EditText is always above the keyboard.

Here is some sample code you can try for your viewport listener:

```
rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        int viewportHeightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - rootLayout.getHeight();
        // TODO: Move your editText by viewportHeightDiff, this is how much difference 
        // there is between the viewport height and the screen height
    }
});
```